# java code for username and password

Tags: java, json, eclipse, null

```
package conc;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


public class Test{

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
    final String USERNAME = "abc@gmail.com";

        // This is only a sample. Hard coding passwords in source files is a bad practice.
     final String PASSWORD = "abc";
     URL url = new URL("https://books.zoho.com/app#/contacts");
     URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();   
     urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
     urlc.setDoOutput(true);  
     urlc.setRequestProperty("Method", "GET");
     urlc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);    

     // final String URL = "https://books.zoho.com/app#/contacts";



        }

}
```

this is my code  , it says that my USERNAME ,PASSWORD  are not used.

Comment: Yes the message makes sense to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverFlow.  Message is correct you haven't used username and password in you program.

Comment: just a friendly reminder from IDE, ignore it if you like.

Comment: It's right.  Now what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, this is perfectly correct: you don't use those values.

As general advice, read the text of warnings and error messages carefully - in most cases they're pretty clear about what the problem is, and most of the time the problem's what the compiler tells you it is. The IDE will even point out what line the error occurs on. If you're still confused, you can always check Google or here, but in this case the text of the message is self-explanatory.

I'd encourage you to read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) on how to debug small programs.

Comment: but when i tried initializing username and password with a empty field even then its throwing out an error

Comment: Im trying to connect to zoho application through java and all i have is username and password